Power BI convert YYYYMMDDHHMMSS to Date + Time in MS Power BI
Been trying to convert YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format/text (e.g. 20240420174901) to date+time format/type in MS Power BI.
The fastest way I found was by changing the type to Whole Number (unless the column already is), and then adding a new column with the Number.ToText function:
AddColumn(#"...", "new_column", each Number.ToText([source_column], "0000-00-00 00:00:00"))

¿ Wondering if the same could be achieved by just re-formatting or transforming the original text [source_column] into a "0000-00-00 00:00:00" custom format (without going thru the step of adding another column)?

[solved with the help of @RonRosenfeld -- see below]
Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"source_column", each DateTime.FromText(Number.ToText(_,"0000/00/00 00:00:00")), type datetime})


Yes, you can do that.

How do I do this?

Assuming your number string is typed as whole number, as you show in your screenshot: Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"source_column", each DateTime.FromText(Number.ToText(_,"0000/00/00 00:00:00")), type datetime})

The simplest is to just convert the string to a number first. Otherwise the formula gets extremely complicated.

Was this solved?

Have you tried using DateTime.FromText()? That would be the fastest and most reliable.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-fromtext

Tried, but it didn't work, I always need to go thru Number.ToText before running the DateTime.FromText conversion.

@Vasko What was the exact function which you tried? Maybe it needed another option or something.

According to the link posted by @davidebacci, this should work:
DateTime.FromText(Number.ToText(20101231013000), [Format="yyyyMMddHHmmss", Culture="en-US"])

